# Why won't the vertical margins between <p> and <hr> collapse in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, margin

Perhaps I am missing something, but I can't explain this from any IE bug I know of.  Why in this example do the margins of the `<p>` and `<hr>` elements collapse as expected in standards compliant browsers (i.e. FF3, IE8, etc) but not in IE7 (including IE8 compatibility mode)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>IE7 Box Model</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        p {
            border: 1px solid #00f;
            background-color: #fefecb;
            margin: 20x 0 20px 0;
            }

        hr {
            margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
            }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <p>
        box 1
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p>
        box 2
    </p>
    <hr />
    <p>
        box 3
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the [hasLayout bug](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). Here's an extract of relevance:

> ### Margin collapsing
>
> The hasLayout MS-property affects the
>   `collapsing` of margins between a box
>   and its descendants. According to the
>   spec the top margin of a box with no
>   top padding and no top border should
>   collapse with the top margin of its
>   first in-flow block-level child:
>
> - [Collapsing Margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)
> - [Uncollapsing Margins](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins)
>
> In IE/Win this never happens when the
>   box has layout: it seems that layout
>   prevents the margins of the children
>   to stick out of the containing box.
>   Moreover when `hasLayout` is true,
>   either on the container or on the
>   child, other wrong margins
>   computations show up:
>
> - [Margin collapsing and hasLayout](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEMarginCollapseLayout.html)

The best solution is simple but maybe drastic on existing designs: set margins on block elements to `0` and use padding instead so that it's consistent across the browsers. Paddings won't collapse.

Comment: Thanks, firstly I have mis-applied the has-layout fixes when trying to fix this by trying to _give_ my elements layout.  In any case it's easier to give layout than to remove it!  Regarding your solution: I won't be able to use the padding option.  Although I didn't specify it in my original question, I need the `<p>` elements to have a background colour, and to be seperated from the `<hr>` elements with a margin.

Comment: Ugly, but works: use `<br>` accordingly. The background gives the element layout and since you need it...

Comment: ok, the hasLayout explanation was the key.  I didn't try to attack that issue directly, but accepted that I couldn't expect the margins to collapse in this instance.  All that I did was remove all margins from the relevant `<hr>` elements and only apply the margins to the `<p>` elements.  It's not perfect there is still a little bit of expansion when viewed in IE7 compared to FF3/IE8 but not enough anymore to break the layout.  Thanks